# Unable to create multiple subscription using ServiceStack.Stripe

Tags: stripe-payments, stripe.net

I am using ServiceStack.Stripe.dll to create a subscription in stripe. This subscription is for new user creation in our application. Below is code to create a new subscription using VB.Net. This subscription will create when user will register first time to our application.

```
        Dim gateway = New StripeGateway(stripeKey)
        If (list("CouponId").ToString() = "") Then GoTo Line1 Else GoTo Line2
```

Line1:      Dim subscription = gateway.Post(New SubscribeStripeCustomer() With { _
                .CustomerId = "cus_96OuD7MM31KKR3", _
                .Plan = "IGmonthly"
            })

```
        If subscription.Id = "" Then GoTo Line2
```

Line2:      Dim subscription1 = gateway.Post(New SubscribeStripeCustomer() With { _
                 .CustomerId = "cus_96OuD7MM31KKR3", _
                 .Plan = "IG-monthly", _
                 .Coupon ="choicefree2"_
             })

User is created successfully in stripe. Again our requirement is to create another subscription in stripe for same customer when he will purchase “Email on Acid” in our application. To do this task I wrote following code.

```
            Dim subscription As ServiceStack.Stripe.Types.StripeSubscription
            If list("CouponCode") <> "" Then

                subscription = gateway.Post(New SubscribeStripeCustomer() With { _
                             .CustomerId = "cus_96OuD7MM31KKR3K", _
                                 .Plan = "EOAMTH", _
                                 .Coupon = "testc2"
                             })
            Else
                subscription = gateway.Post(New SubscribeStripeCustomer() With { _
                             .CustomerId = "cus_96OuD7MM31KKR3K", _
                                 .Plan = "EOAMTHS" _
                             })
            End If
```

Here again subscription is created successfully but it is ending existing subscription(IGMonthly) and new subscription for EOAMTHS is created. It is overriding existing subscription. Our requirement is to run both subscription for same customer. If user purchases “Email On Acid” then along with IG-Monthly plan he has to charge for EOAMTH plan based on his subscription date.

I have updated old stripe dll and now I am using ServiceStack.Stripe dll (Verson 4.5.0.0) but still this issue did not resolve.

Please suggest me how will I fulfil my requirement.

Thnaks & Regards,

Piyush

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that [ServiceStack.Stripe](https://github.com/ServiceStack/Stripe#stripe) uses the old `/customers/cus_.../subscription` endpoint: https://github.com/ServiceStack/Stripe/blob/5578df821acacfa56b9a18edc49dc8540a0835bc/src/Stripe/StripeGateway.cs#L242

So it can only manage a single subscription per customer. It would need to be updated to use the new `/customers/cus_.../subscriptions` (plural) that was added in API version [2014-01-31](https://stripe.com/docs/upgrades#2014-01-31).

As an alternative, [Stripe.net](https://github.com/jaymedavis/stripe.net) does support [creating multiple subscriptions](https://github.com/jaymedavis/stripe.net#subscriptions).